# how to deal with 3-byte addresses in shellcode

Tags: c, assembly

I'm following the directions in the this tutorial:

http://technicalanarchy.blogspot.com/2013/06/stack-based-buffer-overflow-tutorial_20.html

When I get to the "p system"

part, I can get an address, but it's a 3-byte address 0xffffff.  The tutorial shows 4-byte addresses, and the resultant shellcode requires 4-byte.

Now I've added the \x90 nop code to the end of that 3-byte address in my shellcode and at the beginning but neither helped.

OS is 32 bit Centos 6ish

Comment: A 3 byte address would be what you see on a 24 bit system. Do you really have a 24 bit system? You claim to have a 32 bit system.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, aren't 3-byte addresses valid 4-byte addresses?

Comment: @CarlNorum What is 0x00? Is that a zero byte address? Or a one byte address. I'm perhaps trying to prompt the asker into realising that his system does not have 3 byte addresses and that all addresses are 4 byte addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the address you got. If you found `0x123456`, use `\x00\x12\x34\x56`.

Comment: and everyone, thanks for the responses.  I just don't understand why the system would represent a 4-byte address with just 3 bytes.  But anyway on to David and Dan's suggestion.  I added the \x00 at the beginning (as shown above) and also at the end (just for the heck of it).  No workie.  Here's the actual address: 0x16c1d0, and that is for "system".  "0xbffff918" is for "/bin/bash".  Shellcode is \x00\xd0\xc1\x16\TEST\x18\xf9\xff\xbf.  I get a segfault at 0x5416c1d0.  No bash prompt as suggested by the author.  Ideas?

Comment: I forgot about endians, sorry about that. Based on the segfault address, which has an extra `0x54` (ASCII `T`), I think your shellcode should be `\xd0\xc1\x16\x00TEST\x18\xf9\xff\xbf`. If that doesn't work, you may have a `strcpy` or `strcat` that you need to replace with a `memcpy` - although note, obviously, that if you're relying on a buffer overflow due to a `strcpy`, and there's an ASCII NUL in your payload (and not at the end), you're gonna have a problem no matter how you do it.

Comment: That's what I was worried about.  I did try that technique, and no go, but I'll try recompiling with memcpy.  That's a good idea thanks!

Comment: @user1197457 Do you really think that you have a 24 bit machine?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No I don't think that.  I think it's a 32 bit machine.  It's why I don't understand why I'm looking at a 24 bit address.  If you would be kind enough to point to the right answer though, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Otherwise know that no I don't think I have a 24 bit machine.

Comment: 32 bit machines use 32 bit addresses. Addresses don't exist in isolation is shell code. There's an opcode too. If the opcode takes a 32 bit address, give it one. Can't you see that the address is 0x00ffffff?

Comment: One other thing: as mentioned by Dan, I can add 00 to the address and view it's contents in gdb, so I know that works, but 00s don't work in shellcodes as Dan pointed out.  Thinking I just need to build another machine and hope it doesn't put the system call in such a low address.